# How international is an SMS long number?

Tags: sms

The organization I work for wants to be able to send SMS globally, and it seems like there are plenty of providers for this sort of thing. However, we also want users to be able to opt in globally, and this is more tricky.

I understand long codes are international, and at first I thought that we could just get one long code and be able to receive opt-in messages globally. However, after talking to someone at Clickatell, I found that they sell long codes in ranges, which cover different networks in different countries. This would mean we would have to have multiple long codes, which is both messy and out of our budget.

So I thought that settled it, until I read this paragraph on mNatives' website (http://www.mnatives.com/short-long-code.aspx):

> SMS Long code also known as virtual number is a normal mobile number
>   used exclusively for receiving messages from mobile devices. Messages
>   can be sent from **any international mobile networks**, and is received
>   over the net using our web interface or can be downloaded in real-time
>   by an application using SMPP. Unlike SMS short codes which works for a
>   local geographical area within the operator/s footprint, SMS long
>   codes or virtual numbers that can receive messages from **devices across
>   the world**. These are often used to establish a bidirectional channel
>   of communication between an SMS application or user and the mobile
>   audience that enables the delivery of information on demand SMS
>   services delivering Text Unicode or Binary messages.

That sure sounds like one number can work everywhere--is that what they're saying?

I have been researching high and low, struggling to understand all of this, with no luck. Can anyone give me some insight on how long numbers work? Does the reach of a long number vary according to who you purchase it from? Is this notion of a single global long number even possible?

I'd appreciate your guidance. :) Thanks!

Comment: This is an important question for me too. While it may be "off topic" it is an important decision during the design phase of a software application.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I do some developer evangelism for Nexmo.*

Long numbers (essentially virtual numbers), vary as to their reach. Checkout this FAQ from Nexmo (an SMS API) about the reach of Nexmo's numbers: [Inbound Reach List](https://nexmo.zendesk.com/entries/20284471-Inbound-Reach-List-Who-can-send-SMS-to-my-Inbound-Nexmo-Number-) (I've reduced the list to those numbers with international reach):

```
Country      International Reach
Australia    Yes - see list
Austria      Yes - see list
Ireland      Yes - see list
Lithuania    Probably
Netherlands  Probably
Norway       Probably
Sweden       Yes - see list
Switzerland  Probably
UK (+447xx)  Yes - see list
```

Each 'see list' will lead to a specific list of carriers/networks that can reach the virtual number.

For the greatest international coverage, you'll likely have to acquire a few different numbers; however, keep in mind that the cost your users pay to send an SMS to the number may vary as well. So you may want to consider more than just the reachability of the number.

As to cost, it varies per virtual number. Prices per number from Nexmo range for less than a buck to around 6 dollars per month (with Nexmo inbound SMS message are free).